# MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() always returns 0.0

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I'm currently making an android app in android studio that needs to recognize when audiolevels are above a certain threshold. I'm currently running into the issue that the function MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() always returns 0.0.
I've seen multiple people with this issue but none of them were solved.

My code:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

public void start() {
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stop() {
    try {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public double getAmplitude() {
    try {
        return recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Noteworthy is that the stop() function also does not work properly, but before that is called the getAmplitude() already doesn't work. Also I've figured out myself that it is not the 0 from the catch that gets returned, but the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer after start the recorder to get Max Amplitude Value

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    private int amplitudeValue = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        start(mMediaRecorder);

    }

    public void start(MediaRecorder recorder) {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RecorderTask(recorder), 0, 1000);// will update Max Amplitude Value every 1 second

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private class RecorderTask extends TimerTask { ;
        private MediaRecorder recorder;

        public RecorderTask(MediaRecorder recorder) {
            this.recorder = recorder;
        }

        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(() -> amplitudeValue = recorder.getMaxAmplitude());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but the lambda expression is not suitable for the android environtment. Also the function gets called 30 times per second through another timertask so if I understand correctly this should work the same.

Comment: Okay I got it eventually! There was a bug which was that I made two recorders, one in class scope and one in start(). But that was not the only fix. I also had to initialize the getMaxAmplitude function by calling it in the start function after recorder.start().